# Laravel | retrieving collection with relationship and except specific Ids

Tags: php, laravel

i'm working for a car rental booking system
so my plan is when a customer search if there is a available car in chosen Car Model,
first : get the cars id's already taken for the date chosen by customer
second : get all the cars except the not availavle cars,

```
$collection = Booking::whereDate('dropoffday', '>' ,$date1)
        ->whereDate('pickupday' ,'<', $date2)
        ->get(['car_id'])
    ;
    if ($collection->isEmpty()) {

        $cars = Car::with('marques.images')->get();
        return Response::json($cars);
    }
    $taken = [];
    foreach ($collection as $car) {
        $id = $car->car_id;
        array_push($taken,$id);
    }
    $cars = Car::with('marque.images')->except($taken);
    return Response::json($cars);
}
```

how must i rewrite this line
           $cars = Car::with('marque.images')->except($available);
to get all cars with relationship except not available cars

Comment: Maybe the `doesntHave` method can help you out https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-absence

Comment: What is the relation between `Booking` and `Car` ?

Comment: `Booking` belongTo `Car` and `Car` BelongsToMany `Booking`

Comment: i take it the function of the car -> booking relation is called `bookings`? i update my answer with this info

Comment: yes is called booking , should i use `BelongsToMany` instead of `hasMany` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your relations are set up correctly you can probably use the `whereDoesntHave` method like this:

```
$cars = Car::with('marque.images')->whereDoesntHave('bookings', function ($query) use ($date1, $date2) {
    $query->whereDate('dropoffday', '>' ,$date1)
        ->whereDate('pickupday' ,'<', $date2);
})->get();
return Response::json($cars);
```

Comment: `$date1` and `$date2` undefined

Comment: i get date1 and date2 from ajax query